# Как отметить checkbox по id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно из одной формы чекбоксов передать id и чекнуть на второй форме, теже значения.

```
 $(".zones").on('click', function() {
      var log = $( ".zones :checked" ).map(function () {
      return this.value;
      }).get().join(" "); 
      console.log(log);
      check1 = log;
    })
```

ТАким образом в переменной check1 есть набор чекнутых id. Каким образом мне тот-же самый набор id перенести и чекнуть на другой div -

`$(".cities_zones").checked = true;//где тут указать id ?`

Comment: вы не поверите, внутрь $(".cities_zones") можно передавать не только строковые данные, но и переменные))

Comment: поверю) ну так как с id быть?

Comment: да, массив, возвращает [1,3,4,5...]

Comment: ДА есть массив с всема чекнутыми, как именно их id к `.prop('checked')/.checked = true` прикрепить?

Comment: далее log.each(function(i,el){ $(".cities_zones #" + el).checked = true;  })

Comment: не совсем понял, каким образом `$("#" + log[0]);` и `log.each(function(i,el){ 
          $(".cities_zones #" + el).checked = true; 
      })`    соединить ?

Comment: колдовать я не умею, разметки не вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let map = {};

// Кэшируем чекбоксы второй группы
$('#form2 input').map((_, e) => map[e.dataset.group] = $(e));

$('#setBoxes').on('click', e => {  
  // Обнуляем все старые боксы
  $('#form2 input').prop('checked', false);
  
  // Перебираем все отмеченные боксы
  $('#form1 input:checked').map((_, e) => {
    if(e.dataset.group in map)
      map[e.dataset.group].prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form1'>
  <label>Dr. Who: <input type='checkbox' data-group='1' /></label><br />
  <label>Dr. House: <input type='checkbox' data-group='2' /></label><br />
  <label>Dr. Cox: <input type='checkbox' data-group='3' /></label>
</div><br />
<input type='button' id='setBoxes' value='Отметить' /><br /><br />
<div id='form2'>
  <label>Dr. Who: <input type='checkbox' disabled data-group='1' /></label><br />
  <label>Dr. House: <input type='checkbox' disabled data-group='2' /></label><br />
  <label>Dr. Cox: <input type='checkbox' disabled data-group='3' /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: теперь ты должен объяснить что такое `(_, e) =>` :)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, это [стрелочные функции](http://frontender.info/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/). Очень удобная вещь.